# Error when parsing string into DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I've used `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse string into date before, but today I found a problem and I get null from this call.

```
echo $date_string;
$test = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y, H:i:s T', trim($date_string));
echo $test->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

#### Output:

```
Oct 16 2013, 15:45:02 CEST

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in (...) on line 51
```

Where line 51 is the last line where I call `format()`.

So, am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

---

The output of `DateTime::getLastErrors()` as requested:

```
(
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 4
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [3] => Unexpected data found.
            [11] => Unexpected data found.
            [22] => Unexpected data found.
            [36] => The timezone could not be found in the database
        )

)
```

The catch, requested by [@whizzzkid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19338725/1488993):

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Oct&nbsp;16&nbsp;2013,&nbsp;10:00:00&nbsp;CEST) at position 3 (&): Unexpected character
```

Comment: Catch error, see what it says.

Comment: @DevlshOne He echoed `$date_string`.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with [this](http://ideone.com/rerelI) - you must of passed it a string that it wasn't expecting so `$test` has become `false` on failure.

Comment: Maybe your system's timezone table isn't complete, so it doesn't recognize the zone `CEST`.

Comment: Hmmm... I get `2013-10-16 15:45:02`. Don't see a problem.

Comment: Use `DateTime::getLastErrors()` to see your error

Comment: @u_mulder I just edited the question with the output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string contains UTF non-breaking spaces instead of normal ones. Date parser is unaware of them and does not treat them as whitespace. Replace non-breaking spaces with normal ones with something like:

```
$date_string = preg_replace('~\x{00a0}~u', ' ', $date_string);
```

Comment: Well, that is indeed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Very helpful! When scraping sites look at the source when something doesn't work as expected. Ran across something very similar and this is a much easier and cleaner approach than I originally came up with.

Answer (score 2):

can you please try this:

```
<?php
//some $date_string exists
try {
    $test = new DateTime(trim(html_entity_decode($date_string)));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}

echo $test->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Try this one!... should work

Comment: Yes sir. Output: `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Oct&nbsp;16&nbsp;2013,&nbsp;10:00:00&nbsp;CEST) at position 3 (&): Unexpected character`

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem in my CI project. I solved it with this method, it works:

Instead of this:

```
$test = new DateTime($date_string);
```

or

```
$date_string = preg_replace('~\x{00a0}~u', ' ', $date_string);
```

as suggested by @Leo Nyx,

I solved it with this:

```
$date = new DateTime(strtotime($date_string));
```

and then below it, format the time as you please:

```
$date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Off course I already tried solutions posted here. The pre_replace method works, but I think the method I posted here saves you some CPU for good.

The main reason to do this is: somehow your date string contains some characters which DateTime method don't know! strtotime() method correctly converts your string to the date format.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate cause to this problem:

I had my date formated with 24 hour time ("H") and am/pm ("a") which confused the parser.  So I changed my date format from this:  "Y-m-d H:ia T" to "Y-m-d h:ia T"  (note the "h") and it all worked correctly.